# NSURLSessionDataTask delegate methods are not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to download some JSON from an API. Right now nothing gets printed.

I know for sure that the path and the API Key/Value works, because I did it with the NSURLSessionDataTask with the completion handler, but I wanted to learn about how to do the same with delegate methods.

But I cant seem to figure out why my delegate methods are not called.

```
@interface MetaData () <NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate>

@end

@implementation MetaData
-(void)downloadData
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    [sessionConfig setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ header : key}];
    NSURLSession *defaultSesh = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSesh dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
    defaultSesh = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    [dataTask resume];


}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"here 2");
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"here");
    _weaponDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:kNilOptions
                                                          error:nil];
    NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", _weaponDictionary);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

```
defaultSesh = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

by adding that line, i set the delegate to self. So now I print "here 2" but still dont print the dictionary...

Comment: did u set the delegate properly ?

Comment: did u include NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate in your class ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the method

```
+ (NSURLSession *)sessionWithConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration
                                  delegate:(id<NSURLSessionDelegate>)delegate
                             delegateQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
```

to set the delegate properly.

Update:

And you have to call the completion handler of `didReceiveResponse`

> *completionHandler*
>
> A completion handler that your code calls to continue the transfer,
>   passing a constant to indicate whether the transfer should continue as
>   a data task or should become a download task.
>   • If you pass `NSURLSessionResponseAllow`, the task continues normally.
>   • If you pass `NSURLSessionResponseCancel`, the task is canceled.
>   • If you pass `NSURLSessionResponseBecomeDownload` as the disposition, your delegate’s `URLSession:dataTask:didBecomeDownloadTask:` method is called to provide you with the new download task that supersedes the current task.

For example

```
- (void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
           dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask 
 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler
{
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
}
```

Comment: AH! I did forget to set the delegate to self.

Comment: hmmm, but the method by default is void. What am I supposed to return then?

Comment: You have to call the block passing a value, not return something. I added an example.

Comment: THANK YOU! for you help! I appreciate it. This worked wonderfully.

Comment: how did you set the delegate? @Changerrs

Comment: @RajuIstalla delegate:self

check my edit, thats where I set the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue and was stuck for a really long time when I finally got the answer. Hope it helps for those who search for a similar issue

Swift

// create a URLSessionConfiguration object

```
`let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
 config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
 mySession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)`
```

// make a request

```
`let myTask = mySession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest , completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{
            print(response)
        }
    })
    myTask.resume()`
```

// if there is a redirect required implement the delegate method

```
`func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
```

var newRequest = URLRequest(url:(request.url?.absoluteURL)!)`

// take the URL request from the delegate method and make a new task to begin

```
 `let newDataTask = nestSession.dataTask(with: newRequest)
  newDataTask.resume()
```

}`

// implement the delegate methods to capture the data

```
`func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    NSLog("task data: %@", data as NSData)
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set delegate first in **viewDidload**

```
id <NSURLSessionDelegate> delegate = [[Your_ViewController alloc]init];
```